# Horizontal Navbar (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, navbar

I'd like to create a very simple horizontal navbar based on the following HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ol class="clear">
        <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
            <ul class="clear">
                <li><a href="#">Child 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Child 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Child 3</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Parent 3</a></li>
     </ol>
</div>
```

..it would show subnav (if exists) on mouseover.

I know about the great SuperFish plugin, but I'd like to keep it really simple here and not use any plugins if possible.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started in the right direction

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div#nav > ol.clear > li > ul").hide();
    $("div#nav > ol.clear > li:has(> ul)").hover(function() {
        var x = $(this);
        x.children("ul").eq(0).css({'top':x.position().top + x.height()+5, 'left':x.position().left-37}).show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).children("ul").eq(0).hide();
    });
});

<style type="text/css" media="screen">
ol > li { display:inline; margin: 2px}
ul { position:absolute }
ul > li { display:inline }
ul > li > a { yellow; display:block }
</style>
```

Check this site for a demo http://jsbin.com/ejuxa

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any plugins, why don't you just do it with CSS?  Here is a link to the "Ultimate" CSS drop down menu.  Why use javascript when it can easily be done in plain ol' CSS?

**EDIT**

Sorry here is the link: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/final_drop.html

I just tested this in Firefox 3.5, Safari 4, IE8, and Chrome 3 and it worked fine in all of them.